# storage class specified for 'FileCase' error

Tags: c++, global-variables, extern, storage-class-specifier

I tried to compile some code however am getting the error

```
  storage class specified for 'FileCase'
```

What does this error mean?

Does it have to do with the fact I have declared it as an extern int in the private part of the header file ?

I am unable to resolve the issue. In the cpp file, I have declared it as

```
  int FileCase =0;
```

inside of the function where it is needed however it does not resolve the problem. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Thanks

Jis

Comment: I think you should declare FileCase in the .h file, not the .cpp file, then assign it value in the .cpp. I'm not sure if this is the exact error. Anyway, I need more code.

Comment: what means private part of the header file? how can a header part be private? it is declared in a class as extern int?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in the .h file you should have:

`extern int FileCase;` but not in a class...

and in the cpp file you should have a global variable:

`int FileCase = initializer;`